# Python secondary sorting list of index, key from multiple lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to perform a secondary sorting with `list.sort()`, and here is my code:

```
index_list = list(range(12))
a_list = [5, 5, 5, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 8, 8, 10]
b_list = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 10]

index_list.sort(key=lambda x:(a_list[x], b_list[x]))
print(index_list)
```

The result was `[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 1, 2, 9, 10, 11]`, while I expected the last three items to be `[..., 10, 9, 11]`.

I thought it should do secondary sorting (based on the value of `b_list`), but seems that it didn't.

---

EDIT: typo fixed.

Comment: Why did you expect 10, 9, 11?  The tenth value in the `b_list` is 3, which is less than the 9th value, 2.  Default sorting is smallest to largest, so it will come after.

Comment: What `c_list`? In your question, there is only `a_list` and `b_list`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
index_list.sort(key=lambda x:(a_list[x], -b_list[x])) # because -3 < 2 and by default it sorts in ascending order
```

Output

```
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 1, 2, 10, 9, 11]
```

Comment: OMG didn't noticed that! That was a dumb one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
index_list.sort(key=lambda x:(a_list[x], -b_list[x]))
```

instead of

```
index_list.sort(key=lambda x:(a_list[x], b_list[x]))
```